# Get JDBC connection working in play framework (java)

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework, h2

Was wondering, what steps am I missing to get a jdbc embeded h2 database working in my play application?  Following [these docs.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaDatabase)

1. So far editted Application.conf file to contain this:


            db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
            db.default.url="jdbc:h2:databases/test"
            db.default.user=test
            db.default.password="testtest"
2. Next I created a libs directory and added the jar file

           h2-1.3.174.jar

   Is this necessary or does the provided driver handle all types of h2 databases (embeded and server - I know it handles in memory)?
3. Now in the controler how can I access the database?  Do I have to start/shutdown the database?
4. I know I can get connections from the getConnection() method in play.db.  But everytime I execute a statement through this connection I get an exception saying no data is available. If I then check - looks like directory 

            databases/test


   was not created so no database files exist.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

H2 works out of the box. Just create a new project in the terminal.

Otherwise, to your listing:

1. I think you should change `db.default.url="jdbc:h2:databases/test"` to `db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"`
2. don't need to create lib directories. It's all handeled by the build in dependency mgmt **sbt**
3. Just use the model objects and call `save/update`. No need to call `start/shutdown`
4. you are in a framework, it's all there ready for you...

I think you should start reading the documentation from the beginning to the end and examine the example applications. It's all there what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks - to clarify, I don't think I can use h2:mem:... as I need the database to not be an in memory.  It needs to be persisted.  do  I have to use mem:?

Comment: I used H2 for development and testing. Later you can connect the application with a sql database like mysql: `db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname"`, you'll need a connector library, declare it in the `project/Build.scala`, `"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"`

Comment: Just to make sure - once I change something in the database, is it automatically saved or do I have to call some kind of save/update method?  Just got an embedded h2 db working and it seems to be correctly saving everything.  I only ask because of your third bulletpoint

Comment: Model instances have save() and update() methods that act as they are named.

Comment: New operator for creating the model entity, save method for the persistence, update to make changes. Use unit tests, best way to learn. Don't forget to vote the answers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to myborobudur's answer I'll only mention, that you don't need to use memory database, as you can for an instance use file storage (**Embedded**) or even run H2 as a server and then connect to it with TCP in **Server Mode**... Everything is clearly described in [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html).